# Print size of image without DPI

Tags: printing, printer, images, resolution, dpi

If I have image which is e.g. 240 x 320 (width x height) pixels and has 300 DPI then the print size will be: 0.80 x 1.07 inches (see image with goat). Those numbers are computed as width/DPI and height/DPI respectively. This can be verified e.g. under image properties as a print size in both irfanview and xnview. But what if image does not have an DPI (see image with squares)? What will be the print size of this image? How is it possible that the picture has no DPI?

PS: For 684 x 468 pixel image (image with squares) Irfanview shows that print size will be 9.50 x 6.50 inches. Based on above formula (width/9.5 and height/6.5) the calculated DPI is 72. Why 72, is it some standard for printing pictures o what? If I resize this image to 2048 x 1402 then the DPI is automatically set to 72, why?

PPS: what will be the print size of 300 DPI image printed on 72 DPI printer?

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pictures are bitmaps (made of pixels) and don't have DPI (resolution), they have only dimensions (width/height in pixels).

The *devices* where you show them have a resolution in DPI. Display, paper, everything that has got dots when it shows the picture.

Sometimes the metadata of a picture can store DPI to give a hint how large the picture should be when it's on a device. Applications can interpret this hint in various ways and also ignore it.

There is no general answer how these DPI values in metadata are understood. Most usable solution is to tell an application how large you want the picture (in cm/inch). It will check the device's resolution and calculate the scaling factors for you.